# Getting strange LD_PRELOAD errors and missing include files - is my distro busted?

Tags: linux-mint, header-file, ld

For the past half-day or so, I've been having at least the following problems:

1. I get errors about missing LD_PRELOAD entries: My `LD_PRELOAD` contains `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` (not sure if that makes sense), but that file is missing, so whenever I run anything, I get:

   ```
   ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib64/libstdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
   ```

so, I looked at LD_PRELOAD, and it turns out to contain /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 - which doesn't exist.

2. When trying to build projects with CMake, configuration fails, with errors such as:

   ```
   In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:23:0,
                from /home/eyalroz/src/mine/cuda-api-wrappers/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:
   /usr/include/sched.h:28:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
   ```

but my `stdddef.h` is safely in `/usr/include/linux/stddef.h`.

I use GNU/Linux Mint 18.3, and I've not done anything weird with my system lately (well, not that I can remember anyway).

Comment: Regular usage of Unix does *not* require `LD_PRELOAD`, and the now-missing file makes me wonder if it is/was some kind of malware. Not being a malware expert, I'm just leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Did you by any chance try to install a different compiler?

Comment: @StephenKitt: Nope.

Comment: I’m voting to close this as unreproducible because it’s caused by a piece of proprietary software which others are unlikely to encounter (hopefully).

Comment: @StephenKitt: It's reproducible by putting junk in your `.bashrc`, which could happen for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: “which could happen for all sorts of reasons” — which is exactly why it’s not very useful. But it’s a vote, so it will only be closed if others agree.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happened: I was building this program from sources. The genious maintainers decided that:

1. Everybody was running on the exact same machine and OS configuration as them
2. They need to put all of their settings in your `$HOME/.bashrc` so they can make assumptions in the build scripts.

That got my `.bashrc` littered with an `export CC`, `export CXX`, `export C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD` and more stuff. And that messed things up.

Lesson learned: Always check your `~/.profile`, `~/.shrc`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.login`, `~/.bash_login` for weird new entries.

Comment: To make this useful for others, would you mind naming and shaming? I take it this is one of the many mining programs doing the rounds.

Comment: @StephenKitt: It's not a publicly accessible piece of software.

Answer (score -1):

Using `LD_PRELOAD` as a standard setup is a **really bad idea** since it may affect the behavior of all software you run.

The intended use of `LD_PRELOAD` is mainly debugging and as a secondary use case you might replace the default `malloc()` implementation by another that better fits you usage.

Let me give an example when `LD_PRELOAD` is used for debugging. Let me assume, you have a program that starts to dump core and you suspect that this might be a result of a NULL pointer dereference. In this case, you may call:

```
LD_PRELOAD=0@0.so.1 program
```

and if this no longer dumps core, you verified that there was a NULL pointer dereference.

BTW: if you like predictable builds, your build environments should do this:

```
# clear environment variables we know to be bad for the build 
unset LD_OPTIONS 
unset LD_AUDIT          LD_AUDIT_32             LD_AUDIT_64 
unset LD_BIND_NOW       LD_BIND_NOW_32          LD_BIND_NOW_64 
unset LD_BREADTH        LD_BREADTH_32           LD_BREADTH_64 
unset LD_CONFIG         LD_CONFIG_32            LD_CONFIG_64 
unset LD_DEBUG          LD_DEBUG_32             LD_DEBUG_64 
unset LD_DEMANGLE       LD_DEMANGLE_32          LD_DEMANGLE_64 
unset LD_FLAGS          LD_FLAGS_32             LD_FLAGS_64 
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH   LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32      LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64 
unset LD_LOADFLTR       LD_LOADFLTR_32          LD_LOADFLTR_64 
unset LD_NOAUDIT        LD_NOAUDIT_32           LD_NOAUDIT_64 
unset LD_NOAUXFLTR      LD_NOAUXFLTR_32         LD_NOAUXFLTR_64 
unset LD_NOCONFIG       LD_NOCONFIG_32          LD_NOCONFIG_64 
unset LD_NODIRCONFIG    LD_NODIRCONFIG_32       LD_NODIRCONFIG_64 
unset LD_NODIRECT       LD_NODIRECT_32          LD_NODIRECT_64 
unset LD_NOLAZYLOAD     LD_NOLAZYLOAD_32        LD_NOLAZYLOAD_64 
unset LD_NOOBJALTER     LD_NOOBJALTER_32        LD_NOOBJALTER_64 
unset LD_NOVERSION      LD_NOVERSION_32         LD_NOVERSION_64 
unset LD_ORIGIN         LD_ORIGIN_32            LD_ORIGIN_64 
unset LD_PRELOAD        LD_PRELOAD_32           LD_PRELOAD_64 
unset LD_PROFILE        LD_PROFILE_32           LD_PROFILE_64 

# 
# force locale to C
unset LC_ALL
LC_COLLATE=C;   export LC_COLLATE 
LC_CTYPE=C;     export LC_CTYPE 
LC_MESSAGES=C;  export LC_MESSAGES 
LC_MONETARY=C;  export LC_MONETARY 
LC_NUMERIC=C;   export LC_NUMERIC 
LC_TIME=C;      export LC_TIME
```

in a script that controls automated builds or in a makefile in case that you use a make implementation that supports to manage environment variables from within makefiles. Editing the user's  environment could be seen as a **bad guys act**.

Comment: I don't see why I would force the locale to C. It is what it is. Other than that +1.

Comment: This is what larger project tend to do. If you are sure that you don't need it, be free not to do so. BTW: in the early 1990s, there have been C compilers that did not parse floating point constants correctly in case they have been run in a non-C locale since most locales in the world use a comma as fraction separator.